# C++ Make derived class instantiable only from factory / base class

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, design-patterns

I'm modelling classes to represent modules with sub-modules and so on. I make each sub-module to derive from the base class (Module).

But now I want to make it impossible to create sub-module from anywhere else than some specific method (like Factory pattern) - in order to provide some configuration for the sub-modules. See the code:

```
class Module
{
    public:
        template<typename T, typename... Args>
        std::shared_ptr<T> addSubModule(Args&&... args)
        {
            std::shared_ptr<T> module = std::make_shared<T>(args...);

            children.emplace_back(module);
            module->parent = this;

            return module;
        }

    protected:
        Module* parent = this;
        std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Module>> children;
};


class SomeSubModule : public Module
{
    public:
        SomeSubModule(int param1, int param2)
        {
            // ... some init
        }
};


void Usage()
{
    Module rootModule;

    rootModule.addSubModule<SomeSubModule>(1, 2);   // <-- Way 1) This is what I want
    SomeSubModule sub(1, 2);                        // <-- Way 2) This also works, but I want to prevent it
}
```

I want to make the "Way 1" the only way (so I can perform some init stuff in addSubModule, like add newly created module to a vector of children, init the parent pointer, etc).
The way I wrote it, the "Way 2" is still possible and I don't want it.

Answer (score 5):

Generally, when we want to control the construction of a class (say, it only ever gets heap allocated with smart pointers, never declared as a local value) you do that by not making the constructors public!

The constructor should be non-public and only accessible by the other code that is supposed to use it.  The simple way is to use `friend`.  In Boost you can find more complex ways like declaring another type that serves as an access pathway, and that's handy for wrangling large numbers of submodules.

Comment: Something like this `class Module{ class submodule{...}; };` would this be a good design pattern in C++?

Comment: Making the `submodule` a member of `Module` would make it awkward to use the syntax desired.  Organizing the names is unrelated to the problem and solution, so maybe you think this is doing something...?

Comment: @JDługosz So you mean, that each sub-module class would have to make its constructor private / protected, and then declare `Module` as their friend. That's one possibility. The thing is that the protection is left to the author of sub-module and subject to his knowledge of such necessity. You can think of `Module` as a framework / library, that other will use. I was looking for some elegant solution, where this "protection" would be imposed automatically, e.g. by inheriting from `Module`.

Comment: Can you point to particular case from Boost? Maybe I can take a look how they implement it.

Comment: Right solution (+1) but could use an example to demonstrate. Maybe a quick hack that demonstrates what you describe with a factory function.

Comment: @zupazt3 even if the friendship could be automated, the author of the submodule class still has to *not* make any public constructors.